# Adobe air mobile upload File

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I am trying to upload file. using 
flash.filesystem.File 
But the application keep crashing

```
private function uploadFile(f:File):void
{
f.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, uploadProgress);
f.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, callBackFunc);
f.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA , callBackFunc);
f.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, uploadError);
f.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, uploadError);   
f.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, uploadError);
f.upload(urlRequest,"Filedata",false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I have serialize and deserialize the Class that had the File Class

to Local shared objects
File that were deserialize and I don't know way case the app to crash 
I replace the serialization of File to serialize only a string to the file path

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting either an `undefined` error or a `null reference` error? That's because you are passing in `file` as an argument and then accessing `f` in the function.

```
private function uploadFile(file:File):void
{
    file.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, uploadProgress);
    file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, callBackFunc);
    file.addEventListener(DataEvent.UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA , callBackFunc);
    file.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, uploadError);
    file.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, uploadError);   
    file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, uploadError);
    file.upload(urlRequest,"Filedata",false);
}
```

Comment: No that not that and there is no exception the app crash in air simolator as well in the android device

Comment: Then we need to see more of your code, since all you do here is show the event listening...

Comment: Josh Janusch Try any file with adobe air 3.9 it will crash

Comment: Show us more code. I can assure you, using `File` in this manner produces no errors for me in AIR 3.3-4.0 (I've had apps use it using all those releases). Show us your class. Otherwise, we will not be able to help you here.

Comment: Your edit was rejected because you didn't actually include a crash report. Additionally, we will still need to see more code here. There simply is not enough to go off right now

Comment: I am not sure that I understand why it has been rejected I added a like to the crash report? how can I fix it